# X-Pack, an open source or paid?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am new to x-pack and I would like to know whether x-pack is an open source or paid. I was not able to get any information from the elastic website regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53201190/is-security-free-in-elastic-search-stack-features/53201341#53201341

Comment: @Val thanks for this comment. As i read somewhere that X-pack is open now and as i didn't find it in subscriptions page, i was quite confused.Thanks once again.

Comment: XPack is open, which means you have free access to the [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/x-pack), but open != free. There are some XPack features that are free and will always be, but some others will still require a subscription as mentioned in the post I linked to.

Comment: @Val can you please mention the list of free features in x-pack so that it will be helpful for me as well as to everyone who view this post.

Comment: If you click on the link I shared, it's shown in the first two columns of the first image

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that X-Pack has been open-sourced but not all features are free to use. You need a paid subscription to use all features after a 30-day trial.

I'll quote from the [official FAQ](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/open-x-pack) rather than rehashing.

> If the code of X-Pack is open, does that mean it's all free?
>
> No. Many features in X-Pack are free, such as monitoring, tile maps,
> Grok Debugger, and Search Profiler. Some features in X-Pack are paid,
> and require a license that comes with a Gold or Platinum subscription.